# Injectivity of the functor from group actions to permutation representations

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a finite set $X$. We can take the free $\mathbb{C}$-vector space generated by $X$ which we can denote $V_X$. We get a representation of $G$ on $V_X$ coming from the action on $X$. This defines a functor from $G$-sets to $G$-representations. Does this functor fail to be injective? Namely, can we write down an example of $G$-sets $X$ and $Y$ that are not isomorphic but whose associated representations are isomorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transitive $G$-sets up to isomorphism (i.e. $G$-equivariant bijection) are in one to one correspondence with subgroups $H \subset G$ up to conjugacy.  The correspondence just sends a transitive $G$-set to the stabilizer of a point, which only depends on the choice of point up to conjugacy.

On the other hand, up to isomorphism there are the same number of irreducible complex representations  as conjugacy classes in $G$.

So in particular this map can't possibly be injective provided there are more conjugacy classes of subgroups than of elements,  which seems to be the norm provided the group is large enough and nonabelian. For example $S_4$ has $4$ conjugacy classes of elements, but at least $5$ conjugacy classes of subgroups:  The four cyclic ones generated by a single element, plus alternating group $A_4$. (as pointed out in the comments, in fact there are 11 subgroups up to conjugacy)

Comment: I can't find a reference at the moment (was it T. tom Dieck?), but I remember reading somewhere that this holds only for cyclic groups.

Comment: But transitive $G$-sets do not correspond to irreducible $G$-representations. For instance, $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ acts on itself transitively but the associated permutation representation is a sum of characters.

Comment: Haha right, of course it has more than 5 subgroups up to conjugacy.  I never claimed that transitive $G$ sets correspond to irreducible representations, in fact they essentially never do.  The point that is you have #subgroups many permutation reps sitting inside a #conjugacy classes dimensional space of characters, so linear algebra says there must be a linear dependence if #subgroups > #conjugacy classes.

Comment: I see, I guess since this linear dependence relation has integer coefficients, you can move all the negatives to the other side to construct a counter-example to injectivity. Thanks